# Can any one achieve anything in this world?

Tags: life, human, desire

I've seen alot of times. The ability of human is praised.

Swami Vivekanand also said a quote. 
"You Can Do Anything And Everything"

Ive also heard that in the atharvaved it's said somewhere...
"Whatever one wants to become, can become... With desires..." Something like that...

Is it true? Does human beings have this much power?

Comment: NO. Its NOT duplicate.

Comment: No, ine can not achieve anything he wishes.He /she gets what God wishes.He /she can try at best:)

Comment: Swamiji told about the RealmSelf and not about the individual:)

Comment: @commonman But god says he does not interfere with karma?? And it is told that our life is our karma and our choices...

Comment: Please read Gita where Sri Krishna says that God drives everyone like a machine:)

Comment: So long as ego is there, we of course feel that we have some liberty--thats all.And only in attaining God one has been given choice, thus spake the saints.

Comment: So we don't have any choice to choose?? What do we do then?   Sadhguru said... One can live his life the way he wants to...

Comment: @commonman please clear this confusion...

Comment: @commonman Read the original question linked and the example taken carefully. Don't get misled by the title. Even the answer is just repeating the same again. What is the use of this repetition?

Answer (score 4):

In Dattatreya's life, he has spoken of how he had attained Jnana through observing nature around him. In that he mentions, whatever a human thinks of constantly, he attains that form by citing an example.

> The Bhringi or the BEETLE catches hold of a worm, puts it in its nest, and gives it a sting. The poor worm, always fearing the return of the beetle and sting, and thinking constantly of the beetle, becomes a beetle itself. Whatever form a man constantly thinks of, he attains in course of time that form. As a man thinks, so he becomes. I have learnt from the beetle and the worm to turn myself into Atman by contemplating constantly on It and thus to give up all attachment to the body and attain Moksha or Liberation."

http://www.dlshq.org/religions/dattatreya.htm

Comment: This idea is wrongnas is the idea of nurture of the torties babies by the mind of their mother or chhataka drinking only the rain water etc.No insect becomes another insect by thinking !

Comment: @commonman No its true fact. Its there in ancient Texts of Agastya, Bhogar, Thirumoolar too! But I dont find source it in net to share!

Comment: It has been never observed empirically. What happens is well documented:)

Comment: And I hv seen myself also:)

Comment: It is said about a particular kind of wasp and not for bettles though so far as I know.

Comment: @commonman if possible I'll add tamil texts but hard to find in net than books. There is Pazham thinni vavval (BAT) which doesnt have asana vayu to excerete and throws off excrete by splitting via mouth. There's no natural death for snakes.... like this there are many

Comment: Yes that I am not denying.The same was said by Sri Ramakrishna also.But what is not correct is not correct.Each manifestation is a limitation--as said Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: @commonman what is not correct is not correct? Each has its limitation but each have their own uniquness. Other creatures dont have ego of humans and hence they are more connected with five tattvas of nature and have speciality. Crows no when it ll rain, and even those days, kings in war took crows to find out their soliders who are alive and dead as crow pokes dead bodies alone.... Apart from humans, all other creatures have more divine qualities which cannot be explained or understood in today's world!

Comment: @commonman Lambika Yoga came from snakes only. Snakes if you keep it in a place completely devoid of air, Snake rolls its tongue backwards and sits there for yugas... And Moor frog lives inside big stomes of old ages for more years... And It is from those stones, temples idols are made where moor forg lived.... Ok now am I diverting from topic?

Comment: No, these I dont know.I was talking about the wasp incident only.